# symfony 4.0 failed to install assetic-bundle

Tags: composer-php, assetic, symfony4

I'm trying this new symfony 4.0, so I failed to install assetic-bundle,
the command I use

```
composer require assetic-bundle
```

I got a set of problems :

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- symfony/assetic-bundle v2.8.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0
-> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev,/....../  v3.4.0-RC2]
but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I got four problems like this (I just took the important part of the first because they are very long)
my requirements in the json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^4.1",
    "symfony/asset": "^4.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.0",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0"
},
```

hearing from you, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `sanpi/assetic-bundle`.

It's the same `assetic-bundle` but implemented by other people right for using in symfony 4. You don't need even to change any namespaces or class names in your `Kernel.php` or in other code.

Had the same problem after upgrading from 3.x version and this really helped.

Comment: You're free to use that bundle, but as Symfony evolves, this might not be the best choice. It relies on other parts from the Symfony eco system that move further, and looking for workarounds is not a good long-term solution

Comment: I know it, but... Sometimes your real-world project doesn't have enough resources to follow all recommendations and refactor huge parts of your code. Really. In my case I needed a fresh version of api-platform and haven't find any other option.

Answer (score 1):

Assetic-bundle is not compatible with symfony 4. If you want to work with assetic, then choose the symfony 3.4 version.

[Official recommendation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/assetic.html) is to use webpack encore